# Give input to hadoop job through code

Tags: c#, azure, hadoop, azure-hdinsight

I am beginner to hadoop. I want to understand the flow of the map reduce function. I am a bit confused that how do I give input to map job through the code and not by any file. How should I configure it. Kindly assist me. Here is my code.

```
    public class TemperatureMapper : MapperBase
        {
 private static int MISSING = 9999;

            public override void Map(string line, MapperContext context)
            {

                //Extract the namespace declarations in the Csharp files
                string year = line.Substring(15, 4);
                int startIndex = line[87] ==  '+'?88 : 87;

                int airTemp = int.Parse(line.Substring(startIndex, 92 - startIndex));

                string quality = line.Substring(92, 1);

                Regex r = new Regex(quality, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                Match m = r.Match("[01459]");
                if (airTemp != MISSING && r.Match("[01459]").Success)
                {
                    context.EmitKeyValue(year.ToString(), airTemp.ToString());
                }
            }
        }



        //Reducer

        public class TempReducer : ReducerCombinerBase
        {
            //Accepts each key and count the occurrances
            public override void Reduce(string key, IEnumerable<string> values,ReducerCombinerContext context)
            {
                //Write back

                int maxvalue = int.MinValue;
                foreach(string value in values)
                {
                    maxvalue = Math.Max(maxvalue, int.Parse(value));
                }
                context.EmitKeyValue(key, maxvalue.ToString());
            }

        }



static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            try
            {

                string line;
                StreamReader file = new StreamReader("temp.txt");

                ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
                while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    al.Add(line);
                }
                file.Close();

                string[] input = (string[])al.ToArray(typeof(string));




                Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("HADOOP_HOME", @"c:\hadoop");
                Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("Java_HOME", @"c:\hadoop\jvm");

        var output = StreamingUnit.Execute<TemperatureMapper, TempReducer>(input);//this code is executed successfully


//runnning the job in azure
var hadoop = Hadoop.Connect(); // connected to hadoop successfully
                var config = new HadoopJobConfiguration();
                hadoop.MapReduceJob.Execute<TemperatureMapper, TempReducer>(config);//how to I provide input here... 
                Console.ReadLine();             

            }
```

I get the correct result through streaming unit. Now, I want to execute this job in the azure. So how do I give input through the code and not by files?
I have given the input through config i.e.

```
config.AdditionalStreamingArguments.AddRange(input); //input is array of string
```

but when I execute the job this exception occurs:

```
The argument must not be empty string.
Parameter name: blobName
```

Comment: through code means I give the input parameters through c# variables.

Answer (score 3):

Hadoop MapReduce will only operate on files by default (you could write an Storage Handler that was not file based, but that's not very common).

If you are trying to apply MapReduce on something which is generated on a stream, rather than something that exists in files on HDFS you might like to look into something like Storm on YARN instead.

Comment: Acutally, I want to implement Map/Reduce in my other project. So first I will manipulate the data which will in turn become the input to this map/reduce, that's why I don't need a storage for the input

Comment: This line 
        var output = StreamingUnit.Execute<TemperatureMapper, TempReducer>(input);//this code is executed successfully


I provided it string of array as an input and it was executed succesfully. Now, how should I give this similar input to azure hdinsight.

Comment: I have given the input by this way 
config.AdditionalStreamingArguments.AddRange(input); //input is array of string